# How to install google Analytics V3

Tags: android, google-analytics

How to install the latest Google Analytics SDK for my Android App?

I have installed "Google Analytics App Tracking SDK" Revision 3 with the Android SDK Manager.

After that I found a file:

```
libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar
```

in

```
android-sdk-windows\extras\google\analytics_sdk_v2
```

(I assume this is the Version 2)

So, how could I get the newest version of Google Play SDK? (>=3)

Comment: you have v4  which is latest i guess and  all you need to reference google play services and go with smaples

Comment: I also referenced Google Play Services. Package was downloaded and installed. Restarted Eclipse. But now howto go further ? Where is the library which I should copy to my libs folder of my android app ?

Comment: @Raghunandan : Thanks that helped. I referenced the "Google Play Services" and followed the instructions for referencing the googlePlay Services in my Android Project. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The propper answer can be found in the declaration: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#set-up-your-project

However, keep in mind that this is for projects that use Gradle, which means you have to use Android Studio. The declaration also covers setup, install, and how you analyze everything.